# React state reset when re-render occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to make several input elements and print summation of them. So I wrote JSX code like this.

```
const Input = ({reportUpdate}) => {
    const [previous, updatePrevious] = React.useState(0);

    const onUpdate = (e) => {
        reportUpdate(e.target.value - previous);
        updatePrevious(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <input type='number' onChange={onUpdate}/>
    )
}

const Series = () => {
    const [total, updateTotal] = React.useState(0);
    const [inputs, updateInputs] = React.useState([]);

    const updateReported = (delta) => {
        console.log('delta: '+delta+', total: '+total);
        updateTotal((+total) + (+delta));
    }
    console.log('total: '+total);

    const addInput = () => {
        updateInputs(inputs.concat([<Input reportUpdate={updateReported}/>]));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {inputs}
            <p>total: {total}</p>
            <button onClick={addInput}>Add input</button>
        </div>
    )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('react'));
root.render(<Series/>);
```

My compile environment: 7.18.10 (@babel/core 7.19.0) (NPM Babel)

The problem is that state *total* repeatedly reset to it's initial state(0).
Here's my test step.

1. Add 3 input by clicking *Add input* button three times.
2. Write '12' to first input field
   after this, console log printed

```
total: 0
delta: 1, total: 0
total: 1
delta: 11, total: 0
total: 11
```

In my intention, state *total* must be set to 1 in 4th line of log, but it doesn't.

I changed initial state of *total* and repeated test.

```
const [total, updateTotal] = React.useState(10);
```

and console log printed

```
total: 10
delta: 1, total: 10
total: 11
delta: 11, total: 10
total: 21
```

it seems pretty sure that total is not set by *updateTotal* but *useState()*.

what tricky is, making *Input* by hardcoding, not array, thing goes ok. Below code worked as intended.

```
const Input = ({reportUpdate}) => {
    const [previous, updatePrevious] = React.useState(0);

    const onUpdate = (e) => {
        reportUpdate(e.target.value - previous);
        updatePrevious(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <input type='number' onChange={onUpdate}/>
    )
}

const Series = () => {
    const [total, updateTotal] = React.useState(10);

    const updateReported = (delta) => {
        console.log('delta: '+delta+', total: '+total);
        updateTotal((+total) + (+delta));
    }
    console.log('total: '+total);

    return (
        <div>
            <Input reportUpdate={updateReported}/>
            <Input reportUpdate={updateReported}/>
            <Input reportUpdate={updateReported}/>
            <p>total: {total}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('react'));
root.render(<Series/>);
```

So, I think that problem is adding Input element by array, but I cannot figure out why exactly this happens and how to solve this. Can anyone help?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're putting your components in a React state with the *updateReported* version when your **total** is **0**.

Instead of storing your components in the state. Try storing an ID to use as *key* and render them on map.

Like this...

https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-sea-oihz5n?file=/public/index.html:0-1544

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
const updateReported = (delta) => {
    console.log('delta: '+delta+', total: '+total);
    updateTotal((prev) => prev + (+delta));
}
```

Refer below from react official docs for more info
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Answer (score 0):

I come across this a lot, you can try:

```
const updateReported = (delta) => {
    console.log("delta: " + delta + ", total: " + total);
    updateTotal((prev) => prev + delta);
  };
```

It works for me - this way your `total` variable is always up to date :)

The reason this happens is because of the closure. When you first create a new input, its `updateReported` function will think the value of the `total`  variable will be whatever it was when it was first created.